# Excel formulas y reglas

Tags: excel

Tengo un excel donde tengo una columna donde guardo fechas.
Como puedo hacer que si las fechas tienen mas de 30 días de antigüedad se pongan color rojo?
He estado probando con SIFECHA y con formato condicional pero no logro nada
muchas gracias

El formato es fecha corta,y estoy probando esto pero me da fallo:

```
=(C4 – $B$1) <= 30
```

`b1` es donde tengo la fecha de hoy y `c4` donde tengo la otra fecha

Comment: Aprovecho ha dejar esto por aquí: `=SI(=SIFECHA("16/07/1993";HOY();"D")>30;"Greater";"Smaller")` es una prueba tonta que he hecho, que si lo haces todo junto, salta error de analisis de formula, pero si lo haces en dos funciones, sale el resultado correcto. Es porque no se puede poner dos funciones en una misma celda?

Comment: @rencinas si, pero tienes que quitarle el igual de la segunda.

Comment: @GDP Muchas gracias! Dos respuestas correctas en la misma pregunta! Todos los días se aprende algo nuevo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yo las tengo asi:

- En formato condicional.
- Condición: `=HOY()-30`;

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Con la formula =HOY()-30; se pone toda la colummna de color rojo

Comment: @francisco hombre, porque la celda sin contenido tambien te la coge. Aplicale la condicion solo a las celdas que quieres, o controlala para que no coja celdas vacias.

Comment: @GDP http://prntscr.com/irimqh  tengo una fecha de hace 3 días que también se pone de color rojo

Comment: @francisco yo las tengo en valor de la celda es menor que, y luego le pongo la formula.